# Is there a workaround for Chrome not setting dataTransfer object until drop occurs?

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I have an application with multiple drag objects and multiple drop objects. I want to allow drop only when an attribute of the drag object matches the corresponding attribute of the drop object.

This works fine for the ondrop event handler but fails utterly for ondragover, ondragenter and ondragleave events. Apparently Chrome does not initialize the dataTransfer property of the event until a drop occurs.

I've tried using the "this" operator but apparently it does not refer to the calling DOM element as one would expect.

Does anyone know a workaround that allows the ondragover, etc., handlers to find out something about the object that has the handler?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to work around this @IdiotSavant ?